# Track a word/text on specified username on twitter

Tags: python, api, data-mining

I'm a beginner at developing APIs & using Python and currently trying to work with Twitter API. The code I have runs a search on Twitter and functions just like the search bar at the top of Twitter page, where I can replace whatever string I want to look for, in the code. But I would like to do so only for a specific username/account. Do I initiate the call for that username first or do I make a separate code?

```
import tweepy
import sys

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self,status):
        print(status.text)
    def on_error(self,status_code):
        print(status_code)

consumer_key="***"
consumer_secret="***"
access_token="***"
access_token_secret="***"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

if (not api):
    print("Authentication failed!")
    sys.exit(-1)

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
myStream.filter(track=["#nowplaying"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the Twitter API documentation, you will find below trick to filter tweets by user and hashtag

Say user is: your_user
and hashtag is: #stackoverflow

> When you want the most popular tweets of a specific user using a hashtag:
> You want: popular Tweets from @your_user mentioning the hashtag #stackoverflow
> Your search URL is: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3Ayour_user%20%23stackoverflow

Now is specific to tweepy you can try below call to get the data

```
tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="from:your_user #stackoverflow")
```

Reference:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/rules-and-filtering/guides/build-standard-queries